# Find the difference between two time stamps

Tags: php, time, tracking

```
$diff = strtotime(12:00:00) - strtotime(5:01:29);
echo date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

result is 12:01:29

Trying to get the result of 5 hrs 1 min 29 sec

Comment: `$seconds = $diff % 60; $minutes = floor($diff / 60); $hours = floor($diff / 60 / 60);`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the `DateTime` class for time comparison / addition / subtraction:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime();
$dt1->setTimestamp(strtotime('12:00:00am'));
$dt2 = new DateTime();
$dt2->setTimestamp(strtotime('5:01:29am'));
$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $interval->format('%h hrs %i min %s sec');
```

Edit: with the format you gave in strtotime it was thinking 5:01am to 12pm - so it was giving a very different answer than what you wanted, so you need to specify am/pm

Comment: Why don't you just input time to DateTime class? Like `$dt1 = new DateTime('12:00:00am'); $dt2 = new DateTime('5:01:29am');` ?